# Store std::optional value to json file c++

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have a `std::optional<float> test;`

I want to store this value to json file, and since it is optional, I donot know until runtime, if the variable has a value or not. So I am trying to do this

```
frameJson["Test"] = test.has_value() ? test.value() : std::nullopt;
```

But I get this error -

```
Error:Incompatible operand types ('const std::optional<float>::value_type' (aka 'const float') and 'const std::nullopt_t')
```

Question - How do I store the value of std::optional to json in all cases, meaning if its empty, then it has to be `null` or something meaningful.

Comment: You might handle `std::nullopt` in 2 ways in json, with `null` value, or with absent key.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I see, so you basically remove the `{"Test":value}` itself  from json, so that parsing doesnt give undefined value

Comment: Sorry has a botched edit and deleted a comment. I mean, you can not store any value, *or* store `nullptr`, *or* store an empty `json` object. But you cannot do that with a ternary operator. Use a plain old `if`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, yes got the first time itself, avoid adding the object to file if `has_value()` is false, which I think will work in my case

Comment: @Jarod42 absent key works as well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
frameJson["Test"] = test.has_value() ? basic_json(test.value()) : basic_json();
```